# AWS and Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I bought a domain from godaddy ex: yoursite.com.

Right now, I am running WordPress using aws elastic beanstalk and I want visitors to have access from my subdomain.
Let's say I own the domain "http://yoursite.ap-southeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com". How can I link my environment with the subdomain from godaddy. I only found a way to link the primary domain with elasticbeanstalk

Answer (score 1):

Check below screenshot. When you go to edit zone record below settings you have to apply for your subdomain to point to the elastic beanstalk.

[image]

Comment: only work for access subdomain.yoursite.com. Not work if user visit post or page at wordpress

if user click post. link become yoursite.beanstalk again

Comment: That you will have to achieve using your web server or htaccess file. Above procedure is for pointing your subdomain to your elastic beanstalk

Comment: I only found step by step yoursite.com link to elastic beanstalk. any tutorial that i can follow?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want ? do you want to map your site.com to EB or subdomain.yoursite.com to EB?

Comment: only subdomain.yoursite.com and subdomain.yoursite.com/* to EB. I think I need to setup route53 but I dont know how to do it. my yoursite.com using other platform outside aws services

Comment: Do you have a htaccess file?